# When writing an iptables save file by hand, how does one calculate the packet-counter and byte-counter values?

Tags: iptables, rules

I am attempting to write a 22MB `iptables` rule-set file, the very kind that is generated with the `iptables-save` command, except endlessly long.  Understandably, this takes a prohibitive amount of time.  Take this miniature example.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [64:4692]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [72:28512]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9000:9004 -m iprange --src-range 127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Following `(INPUT|OUTPUT|FORWARD) ACCEPT`, there appear value ranges.

> :< chain-name > < chain-policy > [< packet-counter >:< byte-counter >]

These seem dependent on something already stored within `iptables` on the use of `iptables-save`, but, since loading the rules into `iptables` is the problem in the first place, I am unsure how to acquire these values, that I may enter them by hand (by vim, rather), into the final rule-set file.

How might one go about calculating these values?  Is it possible without running another `iptables` command?

Comment: If you are trying to block large amounts of IP ranges, look into `nfblock` which will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using the counters in one of your rules, or need the counters for some other purpose (billing etc), I would just omit them as follows:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9000:9004 -m iprange --src-range 127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

It is possible to see the current counter values using the **iptables --list** command.

```
iptables -L -v -x
```

Note that the counters change as packets are passed down the rules chains, so as soon as you read the counters they may be changed by an incoming or outgoing packet.

Comment: So to verify, I may leave the pair of counters out, entirely?
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
...
Like that?

Comment: Yes, just leave them out (updated answer).